# The float won't work

Tags: css, css-float

I want to create a login form with a vertical line on his right side. Both are included into a div and this is the code

```
<div id="logindAndRegistra">
    <div id="sezionesx">
        <div class="scritta" id="loginHeader">Login</div><br />
        <div class="scritta">Username <input id="username"/></div><br />
        <div class="scritta">Password <input id="password"/></div>
    </div>
    <div id="separatore"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#logindAndRegistra
{
    width:900px;
    margin-top:80px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;  
}


#sezionesx
{
    float:left;
    width:200px
}

#separatore
{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    height:156px; 
    border-color:#000000;
    min-height:20px;    
    margin-left:200px   
}
```

The result is that the vertical line in positioned at the beginning of the parent div, such the login form. Setting "float:left" to the login form, should not allow to position the next element at the end of the predecessor automatically?

Comment: do you want something other than this http://jsfiddle.net/3LdF7/

Comment: not able to get your requirement.

Comment: working fine, http://jsfiddle.net/Cwn4M/

Comment: as above stated this should work fine. But by the way - there is no need to add a line break (`<br />`) after a block element (`<div>`). You can simply remove them.

Comment: Sorry i've done a mistake... Setting margin-left at 200px it's work fine, but if i remove it the separator overlap the login menu.
With the float it should not position automatically on his right?

look there http://jsfiddle.net/3LdF7/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then remove your margin-left:200px from #separatore id and add float:left as below

#separatore
  { float:left; }